# BigQuery/Firebase querying events, order by User Property

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I connected my Firebase Project to BigQuery and received all of yesterdays events today.

I have a user defined event that has an Integer parameter.
And a user property "user_job" of type String (E.g. "Pilot", "Mechanic", "Programmer",...)
I want to know the average of the integer parameter grouped by the user job.

Is there a SQL query that extracts that information?

I know SQL but my problem is that the data is somehow nested in RECORDs and I am not sure how to deal with that.
If it was one row per event and one column per user property I would not have this problem. If it was like this, I could write something like:

```
SELECT AVG( param ), user_job FROM table WHERE event_type = "my_event" GROUP BY user_job
```

But user properties are inside a RECORD (array?) and there are multiple events also inside a RECORD.

Or maybe using SQL queries are the wrong way to deal with requests like that. If so, could someone please point me in the direction.
I see that there are [user defined functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) in BigQuery. So should I create a user defined function that transforms the Firebase BigQuery rows into a flat structure like written above, is that the correct way?

**Update:**
I ran the queries from Sara and Elliot and the bytes processed where the same in both cases (Which is the costs). Saras query ran faster than Elliots, but this might be random chance (and google charges for data, not time).
Even so I marked Elliots answer as final answer, because according to the docs, Standart SQL is the recommended one.
I still don't know how this all compares to UDF and might test that.

**Update2:**
I tested it with a UDF implementation which emitted a new row (language, coins) for every round_completed event. It ran longer and processed more data than both SQL only solutions posted by Sara and Elliot.

```
|_Solution___|_Time___|_Data Processed___|
|Sara        |2.1s    |399 KB            |
|Elliot      |2.4s    |399 KB            |
|UDF         |3.4s    |437 KB            |
```

*Note that the time might be a bad metric, because it is unknown how busy googles data center is at a given time. In the end less data processed costs less. I still included the time, maybe it is useful somehow.

Comment: I now got it to work using a user defined function. Looping through all user properties and all events. I don't know if it is the correct way and will see at the end of the month how much it costs. But it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) rather than legacy SQL for this type of analysis, since it makes the semantics clearer. User-defined functions, especially in legacy SQL, will be more difficult to maintain and more expensive than just using SQL.

Here is a sample query that may help. To run it, uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options" in the UI:

```
SELECT
  user_properties.value.value.string_value as lang,
  AVG((SELECT SUM(value.int_value)
       FROM UNNEST(event_dim),
         UNNEST(params)
       WHERE key = "coins_awarded")) as avg_coins 
FROM 
  `firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607` t,
    UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) user_properties
WHERE 
  user_properties.key = "language"
GROUP BY 1;
```

In this query, the comma operator with `UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties)` returns a row for each element in the repeated `user_properties`:

```
`firebase-analytics-sample-data.ios_dataset.app_events_20160607`,
  UNNEST(user_dim.user_properties) user_properties
```

In the subquery that computes the sum of `int_value` across all repetitions, `UNNEST` is used to turn the repeated `event_dim` and `params` into rows, and the comma operator takes the cross product between them:

```
SELECT SUM(value.int_value)
FROM UNNEST(event_dim),
  UNNEST(params)
WHERE key = "coins_awarded"
```

For more reading about `FLATTEN` in legacy SQL and the equivalent in standard SQL, see [Removing repetition with `FLATTEN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql#removing_repetition_with_flatten) in the migration guide.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this you'll need to [FLATTEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#flatten) one of the repeated fields. Using the sample [Firebase Analytics datasets](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/firebase-analytics-sample-data:ios_dataset), here's a query that does something similar to what you're trying to achieve:

```
SELECT
  user_dim.user_properties.value.value.string_value as lang,
  AVG(event_dim.params.value.int_value) as avg_coins 
FROM 
  FLATTEN([firebase-analytics-sample-data:ios_dataset.app_events_20160607], user_dim.user_properties)
WHERE 
  user_dim.user_properties.key = "language"
  AND event_dim.params.key = "coins_awarded"
GROUP BY 1
```

This gets the average amount of coins awarded for users, grouped by their language preference.

Comment: I got it to work using a UDF that emits a new row that includes the language and coins_awarded. If you compare that to the flatten approach, do you know which is more expensive?

Comment: This is still a bit strange to me, that you can say event_dim.params.key = "something", because event_dim.params is actually a RECORD that contains multiple keys.

Comment: This answer is very nice and working. I marked the other answer by Elliot as correct one, because according to the docs, standard SQL is the recommended way to go. I upvoted both solutions.